# Can I fit road tyres on a cyclo cross bike?

Tags: tire, cyclocross

I've been considering purchasing a Boardman Pro CX Cyclocross Road Bike Large 2010. (Broken link replaced with Google [search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Boardman+Pro+CX+Cyclocross+Road+Bike+Large+2010))

The spec says the wheels are 700C and that it comes with 700 x 35C tyres. I'm wondering, should it be also possible to fit some thinner road tyres with sizes 700x20c, 700x23c or 700x25c?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can! It looks like that bike comes with Mavic CXP23 rims, which can fit down to 19mm tires I think. You would defiantly have no problem with 700x23 tires. I'm surprised it comes with 35, that seems a bit wide for those rims, but you should be OK.

Comment: Agreed that 35 seems way wide for that rim. I would think it would feel really squirmy in turns.

Comment: As cyclocross is so often a muddy sport any extra squirm from tyres is negligible! Seriously though I know a few people who have Boardmans and no one is complaining about squirmy tyres.

Comment: FWIW, in that price bracket I would (and did) look seriously at the Ridley Crossbow (or the X-bow as they're branding it for '11). Although if you're buying from Halfords, I assume it's because of the Cycle to Work, in which case you might not have the flexibility.

Comment: Mount those tires with defiance and abandon.